# who tend not to immunize

Tags: phrases

> Right now it's hard to say if that’s happening, says Deeks, because
>   the number of provincial cases this year has been low. "But we do have
>   pockets where there are groups of people **who tend not to immunize**,
>   and those areas are much more susceptible if mumps is
>   introduced."(*NHL mumps outbreak: 7 big questions answered - CBC news
>   Dec 16 2014*)

Is '**who tend not to immunize**' right? Shouldn't it be '**who tend not to get immunized**'? Thank you.

Comment: You should add some dictionary definitions or other research to support your question. Its often possibe to say things several different ways, but that does not make it wrong.

Comment: Active may be fine here: if the author talks about parents declining the shots for their children, for example.

Comment: Or it could be fine even if it means "get immunized".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is **'who tend not to immunize'** right? Shouldn't it be **'who tend not to get immunized'**?

"Immunize" is usually a transitive verb. I suspect that this usage developed as an abbreviation of "immunize [their] children". The article's version sounds more formal, which (given the context) is probably a factor as well.

Your version is also correct.